# R.string.close ,close cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, mobilefirst-studio

i'm doing my first android learning tutorial , but stuck at this error that the title describes ..this is an app i'm trying to do on Eclipse , java , here is my code..(code is auto generated by the project)

```
package com.HelloWorkLight;
import android.R;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity;``

import com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL;
import com.worklight.androidgap.api.WLInitWebFrameworkResult;
import com.worklight.androidgap.api.WLInitWebFrameworkListener;

public class HelloWorkLight extends CordovaActivity implements      WLInitWebFrameworkListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WL.createInstance(this);

    WL.getInstance().showSplashScreen(this);

    WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);

}

/**
 * The IBM MobileFirst Platform calls this method after its initialization is complete and web resources are ready to be used.
 */
public void onInitWebFrameworkComplete(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result){
    if (result.getStatusCode() == WLInitWebFrameworkResult.SUCCESS) {
        super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());
    } else {
        handleWebFrameworkInitFailure(result);
    }
}

private void handleWebFrameworkInitFailure(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.close, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            finish();
        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.error);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(result.getMessage());
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).create().show();
}
}
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: I think you imported the wrong `R` class. `import android.R;`

Comment: I have it as R.java >> then R class in there , in the /gen folder

Comment: Try replacing `import android.R;` with  `import your.application.package.R`. where `your.application.package` is your application package's name.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue , since java is accessing all the R class components and the error message gets hidden once i create a null string called cancel , but is that really the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check the file `values/strings.xml` to see if there is a string by that name. Otherwise, you can add it:

`<string name="close">Close</string>`

You may also want to try `Cancel` instead of `Close`, as this is general practice.

If that wasn't your problem, usually the problem in these cases is with `import android.R`. Try removing it and doing a clean build of your project.

Note: When you're using stock strings, make sure you use their fully-qualified name to avoid potential problems: `android.R.string.no`, for example.

If the class files aren't in the root package, you import `R` like this: `my.packagename.R`

Comment: Yes i have strings called close and cancel in {values/strings.xml}

Comment: Okay ,question , i have the close / cancel strings in strings.xml but they aren't in the R class , how could i include them proberly to get the error to go away?

Comment: @CriminalDuck You really shouldn't be adding anything to `R`. Have you tried removing the import and doing a clean build? Normally that will remove these issues.

Comment: Yup i've tried that and the same error is poping up , Java suggesting me to create cancel or close string in R class to pass that error , but i don't think i should change anything in the R , and according to strings.xml , my values are already there but are unread .